# How to store data in the ethereum blockchain?

Tags: blockchain

In my application, I need to store my data in the blockchain so that the data is transparent and everyone can see the data. How to store the data so that everyone can see the data? Could anyone help?

Comment: Question is too broad, describe the specifics of your problem, like what type of data, size of the data, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a public blockchain such as Ethereum, develop a smart contract based on your intentions and deploy it to the mainnet. Anyone can see your data on a public blockchain. it is however, up to you, to consider what data is relevant to store on the blockchain and to define access control flow for your decentralised application.